# is it possible to share one method for two child struct

Tags: go

I feel stranded in the inheritance of Go. I defined a struct and its two children like:

```
type Father struct{}
```

```
type Son struct{
  Father
  Name
...
}
```

```
type Daughter struct{
  Father
  Sex
...
}
```

And I have implemented a method of Son as below, and I want to implemented the exactly same method in Daughter without writing the same codes again. The reason why I dont use `func (s *Father) Method` in the very beginning is that it cannot see `Son.Name` which is important in my method.

```
func (s *Son) Method(){}
```

Comment: *"I feel stranded in the inheritance of Golang"* -- You *feel* that way because there is *no* such thing as [inheritance in Go](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance). Don't try to use something that isn't there.

Comment: "I feel stranded in the inheritance of Go." -- Go has no inheritence, so of course you're stranded here.

Comment: The problem I tend to find with these kinds of questions about OOP in Go, is that the examples given to demonstrate when the feature is needed are so incredibly backwards.  Looking at your example type heirarchy and problem here, every detail seems flawed, and it's not clear how you'd ever find this situation when designing with Go principals in mind.

Comment: Also I can't understand why you wouldn't design it as Child struct and then have a gender field inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and I want to implemented the exactly same method in Daughter

Then do so.

> without writing the same codes again.

You cannot do that.

Note that the way you model your logic is doomed to fail. Go has no notion on inheritance and literally *any* attempt trying to mimic inheritance fails.

(On your case you could embed a `type Child {Name string}` with appropriate methods in Son and Daughter, but *please*: let go of traditional OOP.)

Comment: Noted, and thank you for your reply. Or is this alternative plausible if I just write an independent function and make the child struct ```Daughter```as an input param like ```func Method(s *interface{})```?

Comment: @SteveYang 1. **Never** use a pointer to an interface. 2. You you can write a function but would have to do reflection. Don't try if you do not know how to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Update:
I use an independent function like `func Method(s interface{})` to pass in child structs